# Recommendations for a private deb package repository for Ubuntu servers

Tags: apt, server, package-management

At work some teams create internal Ubuntu apps that are built via GitHub action workflows and packaged for Ubuntu as Debian packages. The package files are then uploaded to an Amazon S3 bucket, and we use [freight](https://github.com/freight-team/freight) to rebuild the index after each upload. Each of our ~200 internal Ubuntu servers then uses [apt-transport-s3](https://github.com/MayaraCloud/apt-transport-s3) to download and install those packages.

We are having problems with freight, so among other things, I am looking around for alternatives.

We need the repository to retain a limited number of old releases to allow easy rollbacks, but not to retain everything as one of the projects creates more than one release every day. Ideally we would like to be able to rebuild index within the GitHub action workflow that builds and uploads the package so it can all be self contained. The current freight setup uses an [EC2 T3 burstable instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances.html) which is fairly cheap to run.

The project with very frequent release cadence is also publishing a lot of packages with a complex web of dependences that requires apt to sort out, so it would not be practical to download package files and install them directly, as the wrong packages would be installed.

I have found the [DebianRepository Setup page](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Setup) over on the Debian project, but I am not sure which are worth investigating (there are some dead links).

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, it looks like [Aptly](https://www.aptly.info/) is the best good candidate, though I have not yet used it to implement a solution.